# Show that d such that $f(d)=f'(d)$ exists in the interval $]a,b[$, when $f(a)=f(b)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $d$ such that:

$$f(d)=f'(d)$$

exists when $f$ is continous in the interval $(a,b)$ and has a defined derivative in the interval $]a,b[$, $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Further d exists in the interval$]a,b[$.

I suppose that the Rolle's theorem can be used here, so if the above criterion holds it can be shown that there exists $v$ such that $f'(v) = 0$, but it's difficult to find the right set of functions to prove the result.

Comment: You mean $f(a)=f(b)=0$ on line 4. You also mean that Rolle's theorem can be used to show there is a $v$ with $f'(v)=0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$
g(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}f(x)
$$
The $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and by virtue of Rolle's Theorem $g'(d)=0$, for some $d\in (a,b)$.

Also
$$
0=g'(d)=\mathrm{e}^{-d}\big(f'(d)-f(d)\big)
$$
and hence $f'(d)-f(d)=0$.

Note. Using the same method, one can show that for every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, there exists a $d\in(a,b)$, such that $\,f'(d)=\lambda f(d)$.